# Single-threaded demuxer with FFmpeg API

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a demuxer using FFmpeg API with the next interface:

```cs
interface IDemuxer
{
    void WriteMediaChunk(byte[] chunk);

    byte[] ReadAudioOrVideoFrame();
}
```

The plan is to use it in a single thread like this:

```cs
IDemuxer demuxer = new Demuxer();

while (true)
{
    byte[] chunk = ReceiveNextChunkFromInputStream();
    
    if (chunk.Length == 0) break; // Reached the end of the stream, exiting.
    
    demuxer.WriteMediaChunk(chunk);
    
    while (true)
    {
        var frame = demuxer.ReadAudioOrVideoFrame()

        if (frame.Length == 0) break; // Need more chunks to produce the frame. Let's add more chunks and try produce it again.

        WriteFrameToOutputStream(frame);
    }
}
```

I.e., I want the demuxer to be able to notify me (by returning an empty result) that it needs more input media chunks to produce the output frames.

It seems like FFmpeg can read the input chunks that I send to it using [the read callback](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/avio_read_callback.c#L41).

The problem with this approach is that I cannot handle a situation when more input chunks are required using only one thread. I can handle it in 3 different ways in the read callback:

1. Simply be honest that there is no data *yet* and return an empty buffer to FFmpeg. Then add more data using `WriteMediaChunk()`, and then retry `ReadAudioOrVideoFrame()`.
2. Return `AVERROR_EOF` to FFmpeg to indicate that there is no data yet.
3. Block the thread and do not return anything. Once the data arrives, unblock the thread and return the data.

But all these options are far from ideal:

The 1st one leads to FFmpeg calling the callback again and again in an infinite loop hoping to get more data, essentially blocking the main thread and not allowing me to send the data.

The 2nd leads to FFmpeg stopping the processing at all. Even if the data appears finally, I won't be able to receive more frames. The only option is to start demuxing over again.

The 3rd one [kind of works](https://github.com/yaskovdev/Demuxer/blob/master/Demuxer/Program.cs), but then I need at least 2 threads: first is constantly putting new data to a queue, so that FFmpeg could then read it via the callback, and the second is reading the frames via `ReadAudioOrVideoFrame()`. The second thread may occasionally block if the first one is not fast enough and there is no data available yet. Having to deal with multiple threads makes implementation and testing more complex.

Is there a way to implement this using only one thread? Is the read callback even the right direction?